# Replacing Label with new Label in python

Tags: python, tkinter

So I know the title is kind of confusing but I don't know how to express my problem in a better way, and I am also new to python.

Ok so here's my problem: I have this program that generates a random number when you click a button and then displays that number, but each time you click it displays the new right under the previous one and so I wanted for the number to just change instead of appearing under the previous one, here's my code:

(screenshot: https://gyazo.com/2bc9ae7bbe32c2422c94891ca30b8512 Python 3.0)

```
from tkinter import *
import random

screen = Tk()

def generate():
        random_number = random.randint(1, 1000)
        result = Label(screen, text="Number: " + str(random_number))
        result.pack(side=TOP)

text = Label(screen, text="Click to generate a random number:")
text.pack(side=TOP)

button = Button(screen, text="GENERATE!", command=generate, fg="yellow",                 
bg="purple")
button.pack(side=TOP)

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
def generate():
        random_number = random.randint(1, 1000)
        result = Label(screen, text="Number: " + str(random_number))
        result.pack(side=TOP)
```

with:

```
result = Label(screen)
result.pack(side=TOP)
def generate():
        random_number = random.randint(1, 1000)
        result['text'] = "Number: " + str(random_number)
```

---

Former code creates a *new* `Label` object each time `generate` is called, which would occupy memory; whereas the latter creates `Label` object only once and just modifies its `text` option each time `generate` is called.

**Edit:** Added more explanation in parallel with [Farhan K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5270506/farhan-k)'s comment.

Comment: THANK YOU, IT WORKED! :)

Comment: @Myko FYI, you were originally creating a new label called `result` every time `generate` was called.

Answer (score 0):

Use `place` instead of `pack` using pack you telling the label widget to display the result under the previous one but `place` will display at exact spot by overlapping the previous one.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

screen = Tk()

def generate():
        random_number = random.randint(1, 1000)
        result = Label(screen, text="Number: " + str(random_number))

        result.place(x=650, y=100)

text = Label(screen, text="Click to generate a random number:")
text.pack(side=TOP)

button = Button(screen, text="GENERATE!", command=generate, fg="yellow",
bg="purple")
button.pack(side=TOP)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure it will _erase_ the other so much so overlap?

Comment: sorry for the grammar

Comment: If it doesn't erase, it may cause memory leak.

Comment: @Nae What do you mean by memory leak, want to understand what have done better.

Comment: this still has the original problem of creating multiple labels that may not hide the previous values. The memory leak is that each time `generate` is called, it uses additional memory for the label that it creates. Click it a million times, you have a million labels.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation